# Restricts daemons to open certain ports on linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, port, daemon, restrict

I want to restrict the daemons from opening certain ports, and i wish to achieve it at kernel level. 
I came across an idea, i.e to write my own bind function and then redirect to the original bind function. But the user can bypass this by invoking the system call. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought:

there's a chance that 'iptables' could do the work for you.
Using 'iptables' you can define a rule which will deny outgoing traffic from a port.

This solution may work for you if you can identify the deamon's traffic according to iptables options. It will not work for you if you can only identify the deamon's traffic according to its process id.

Comment: Yes, it will serve the purpose. But i wish to achieve it at kernel level.

Comment: It would help if you explain how iptables *doesn't* suit your needs.

Comment: iptables works on the kernel level. Only the interface is in user space but the actual filtering is done in kernel space - there's no way it could work otherwise.

Comment: Presently i am using iptables to block the ports, but  there is a very high probability if a user gains bash access to my device he can change iptables rules and start up various daemons.

Comment: To modify iptables a root access is required. I believe that with SE Linux you can have a smarter permission mechanism where just a root access would not suffice.

Comment: Another tweak you could do is to wrap iptables with a script that asks for a password before executing the real iptables

Comment: I need to provide root access, it is necessary. Wrapping iptables with a script won't suffice either because in that case my automated rule insertion process will be hindered.